# Is it possible to use alpha-beta pruning for non-zero-sum games with more than two players?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, minimax

I have read somewhere that the minimax algorithm can be generalized for more than two players. Imagine that we have 3 players that each of them want to maximize its own answer. Is it possible to use alpha-beta pruning in this case? or it is useless? why?

**Note:** Games are non-zero-sum.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible because of the following reason. As it mentioned in the question the game is `non-zero-sum`. So there is no competition between the players and each of them wants to maximize its own value. Therefore alpha-beta pruning is not useful here!

For more information read [this article](http://web.cs.du.edu/~sturtevant/papers/NZSPruning.pdf).